# Controller should not have domain logic. How faithful should one adhere to this tenet?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Quoting from page 49 of Pro ASP.NET MVC book

> It is certainly possible to put domain
>   logic into a controller, even though
>   you shouldn’t, just because it seems
>   like it will work anyway. It’s easy to
>   avoid this if you imagine that you
>   have multiple UI technologies (e.g.,
>   an ASP.NET MVC application plus a
>   native iPhone application) operating
>   on the same underlying business domain
>   layer (and maybe one day you will!).
>   With this in mind, it’s clear that you
>   don’t want to put domain logic into
>   any of the UI layers.

Why he seems to contradict himself on page 172?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CheckOut(Cart cart, ShippingDetails shippingDetails)
{
    // Empty carts can't be checked out
    if (cart.Lines.Count == 0)
        ModelState.AddModelError("Cart", "Sorry, your cart is empty!");

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        orderSubmitter.SubmitOrder(cart, shippingDetails);
        cart.Clear();
        return View("Completed");
    }
    else // Something was invalid
        return View(shippingDetails);
}
```

Related to: [How to avoid placing domain logic in controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748696/how-to-avoid-placing-domain-logic-in-controller)

Answer (score 1):

The `if (cart.Lines.Count == 0)` test could indeed have been handled by the validation logic of the model and shouldn't be placed in the controller. Personally I would rewrite this controller action like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CheckOut(CheckOutViewModel checkOut)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        orderSubmitter.SubmitOrder(checkOut);
        return View("Completed");
    }
    return View(checkOut);
}
```